# Objects from a static list being referenced by others lists

Tags: java, object, memory, reference, static

Before anything, I'm using Java. That being said let me start with a sample code.

```
public class Test {

    public void test(){
        List1 list1 = new List1();
        List2 list2 = new List2();
        for(int i = 0;i<1000;i++){
            list1.test1List.add(new Test1());
        }

        list2.test2List = new ArrayList<>();
        for(int i = 0;i<1000;i++){
            Test2 test2 = new Test2();
            list2.test2List.add(test2);
            for(int j = 0;j<1000;j++){
                if(j<i){
                    test2.add(list1.test1List.get(j));
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public class Test1{
        String test1 = "test1";
    }
    public class Test2{
        ArrayList<Test1> list;
        public Test2(){
            list = new ArrayList<>();
        }
        public void add(Test1 t){
            list.add(t);
        }
    }
}
public class List1{
    public static ArrayList<Test.Test1> test1List;

    public List1(){
        test1List = new ArrayList<>();
    }
}
public class List2 {
    public ArrayList<Test.Test2> test2List;
    public List2(){
        test2List = new ArrayList<>();
    }
}
```

My class have two objects, each one has a list, where one is static. The other list references some objects from this static list, in the sample code I did it using a simple condition, but this condition can get really complex.

The issue here is: in my non-static list I have objects pointing to static objects.

So, those references will use some memory (other than the "pointer" usage)?
When my non-static list grows, I will save memory by making the other list static?

Let me add a exemple pic where we can see the non-static list referencing some itens from the static one.

[image: Exemple]

Getting into details: the static list is a list of objects that are construct based on a DataBase, and as they will be referenced by multiple instances of a higher hierarchy I'm looking into making those objects static in order to save some memory.

Comment: I don't understand what your question is.

Comment: When my non-static list grows I will save memory by making the other list static?

Comment: I have extended the code sample by adding the AuditEntity and BalanceEntity classes, that might clarify the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whether you declare a field to be `static` depends primarily on how the field is used, and memory considerations come as a result.

Normally, a non-`static` field is replicated in every instance of the class. So, if you have 10 different `Test` objects, each of those will have its own `audEntities`. However, when a field is `static`, the field is a "part of" the class itself, rather than an instance of the class. So, even if you have 10 different `Test` objects, they all share the same `balEntities`.

As a result, you'll save some memory if:

- you have many instances of your class, and
- the field is declared `static`.

If you only have one instance of the class, then the memory usage is essentially the same.

Of course, before you go declaring everything `static`, you need to think about whether your fields *should* be static. Should they be allowed to change for different instances? That is, can you have two `Test` objects where their `audEntities` are supposed to be different? If yes, then you can't declare `audEntities` static.

Comment: With this new code it seems that making the List1 list static doesnt save me any memory.
But it seems that referencing objects of that list is better than referencing new instances.
I've tested: 
(1) List1 list static
(2) Non-static
(3) Referencing new List1() objects instead of list1.test1List.get(j).
Results: (1) and (2) uses the same memory, whereas (3) uses more (a lot)

Comment: If `test1List` is _not_ `static`: every time you say `new List1()`, you're creating a new `test1List`. If `test1List` _is_ `static`: no matter how often you say "new List1()", you only have a single `test1List`. If you still have a question, can you make it clear what exactly you want to know? The text in your question no longer matches your code example.

Comment: Its ok, your answer helped a lot, I'm sorry if I can't outsource properly my problem